# How to get path to current node with XMLReader in PHP

Tags: php, xmlreader

I have a problrm with geting path to current node with XMLReader. I need something like "getNodePath()" for XMLReader. For example:

```
$reader = new \XMLReader();
$reader->open('/path...');
while ($reader->read()) {
            if($reader->nodeType == \XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->localName == "file"){
                $tags_file['elem'] = clone $reader;
                $tags_file['path'] = $reader->*getNodePath()*;
            }
        }
```